# Import list of addresses into MapPoint for route planning

Tags: import, map-point

I have a list of 40+ points for each work day in a month.
I need to somehow calculate the distance between each of those points for each day.

I have a list of addresses in a database, house number, street, city, zip and state are all in separate columns so I can generate any output using some simple programming.

But I am stuck at importing addresses to MapPoint. I have tried import wizard but all it does is plots points on map and does not add to route planning.

Maybe there is an alternative to this? Or other way around it?

Answer (score 2):

When your data is imported as pushpins, select all the pushpins by holding down your right-mouse button at the upper left of the screen and drag a selection rectangle to the bottom right of the screen.

Go to the Route menu and choose Route Planner. In the newly opened pane, choose Add pushpins as stops.

This issue stucked me too.. I feared I should add all the pushpins one by one!... :D

Then you can click Get directions to calculate the route.

Comment: This will create the route in an arbitrary order, but you can manually set the order. Or set the start & end and then run "Optimize" to find the probable best order. (we also sell a product called MPRouteWriter which can automate some of this multi-point route management)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the imported group list in the Legends and Overview Panel, you can select add points as stops.
My only problem is that they do NOT add the stops if you have them in order on your excel sheet.